# jQuery UI dialog width & height based on screen width & height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Currently (jQuery 1.4.4 and UI 1.8.8) I used the following to set a dialog's properties:
(I'm trying to set the dialog to be 180px less than the height and width of the screen.)

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ 
            bgiframe: true,
            position: 'center',
            width: $(window).width()-180,
            height: $(window).height()-180,
            title: ititle,
            modal: true,
            buttons: { "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("destroy"); }}
});
```

The above works fine in FF but in IE 8 it fails.

Is this the right way to set width and height or should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to specify the DOCTYPE and use standards mode for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me in IE8:

```
var winW = $(window).width() - 180;
var winH = $(window).height() - 180;

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: winH,
    width: winW,
    modal: true
});
```

You'll need this at the top of your page though

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```